Umbraco Backoffice Search - Override functionality in Umbraco back office
Is it possible to override the Search functionality in Umbraco Version 13 back office that uses Examine? When the user searches in the text box, I would like to override this call to the API. The API is:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/entity/SearchAll?query=usa


The short answer is that you should probably not override the out-of-the-box Examine search functionality but extend or replace the available configuration to match your requirements if you can.
Umbraco Search heavily relies on Examine. As a result, overriding Examine will probably require re-writing quite a few existing code, including the BackOfficeExamineSearcher and the related Backoffice AngularJS code. Furthermore, Angular JS is not supported any longer starting from Umbraco v14, which means you will need to create your backoffice front-end code again in v14+.
PS: I have checked the Umbraco CMS code, and I can't see an option for an Examine override.

